# Generate a form to print out in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm curious about how could I generate dinamically and programmatically a page to print out? I mean if I have strings, and for example a source image with a logo, how could I create a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either generate a PDF or an HTML webpage and print either (from withing Qt or externally).

Or you can directly print via QPainter.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to reinvent the wheel. Many book writers including `Beej` use <kbd>[Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Qt5 you can easily create a PDF file which I recommend. I include a very basic example but I recomend to check the documentation for QPainter and QPdfWriter.

```
QString fileName = tr("myfile.pdf");
QPdfWriter pdf(fileName);
QPainter painter(&pdf);
pdf.setPageSize(QPagedPaintDevice::Letter);

// Render whatever you want using the painter functions.

painter.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code needs to add and remove details on the form, coding the low-level geometries for printing will be re-inventing the wheel. You can use the higher-level [QTextDocument](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qtextdocument.html) class to do all the layouts and resizing for you.

Once you've got that all coded in, you can convert to HTML or print to a QPrinter (including PDF).